# Выбор элемента класса по словарю

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, словарь

Есть словарь:

```
var = {
"Слово":"word"
}
```

Также, есть класс:

```
class Cl:
  word = Null
```

Можно ли как-то, взяв значения словаря по ключу,  присвоить ему что-либо в классе?
Например:

```
cl.var['Слово'] = 'foobar'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setattr(cl, var['Слово'], 'foobar')
```

Comment: Благодарю, то что нужно